# Python enumerating - endless loop on list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a login program that checks a list for passwords and usernames. If credentials are found, a dialog window pops-up saying "Success", otherwise it shows "invalid credentials".

However, I am having a problem where for each line it's displaying a dialog window instead of enumerating through the list and then displaying the correct prompt. In short my program is displaying one of the above mentioned prompts for each line.

I'm using PyQt4 for the GUI, here's my code:

```
def process_login(self, username, password):
    loggedin = False
    file = open('acclist.txt')
    login_info = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
    while not loggedin:
        for pos, line in enumerate(login_info):
            if username == line[0] and password == line[1]:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Login Successful')
                loggedin = True
            if loggedin is not True:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning!', 'Incorrect credentials')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. Move your ``if loggedin is not True:`` block to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `while` loop really. You could loop through the file lines, once credentials match you `break`, otherwise if loop ends with no match, then login failed. like so:

```
def process_login(self, username, password):
    loggedin = False
    file = open('acclist.txt')
    login_info = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
    file.close()

    for line in login_info:
        if username == line[0] and password == line[1]:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Login Successful')
            loggedin = True
            break

    if not loggedin:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning!', 'Incorrect credentials')
```

Comment: don't need a while loop : Exactly just use break and move forward. While loop can create problem when there will be no values that are matching. No condition is breaking loop (as `loggedin` is always false)

Comment: @ I have marked yours as best answer however how would i go about changing the code so the file isnt always open?

Comment: @Hellbound_TKR you just need to do `file.close()`, check the answer now, I added this line.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your Dialog is inside the for-loop. Means it is being opened for every element. A way to fix this would be something like:

```
def process_login(self, username, password):
  loggedin = False
  file = open('Accounts.txt')
  login_info = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
  while not loggedin:
      incorrect = False
      for pos, line in enumerate(login_info):
          if username == line[0] and password == line[1]:
              loggedin = True
          if loggedin is not True:
              incorrect = True
      if incorrect:
           QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning!', 'Incorrect credentials'
      else:
           QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Login   Successful')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_login(self, username, password):
    file = open('acclist.txt')
    login_info = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
    while True:
        for pos, line in enumerate(login_info):
            if username == line[0] and password == line[1]:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Login Successful')
                break

        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning!', 'Incorrect credentials')
        break
```

Note: the `while` loop is not important it's used as a context for login success/failed instead of saving outside scope variable

don't forget to `close` the file, a better implementation will be like so

```
def process_login(self, username, password):
    logged_in = False
    with open('acclist.txt', 'r') as read_file:
        for line in read_file:
            if username == line[0] and password == line[1]:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Login Successful')
                logged_in=True
                break
        if not logged_in:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning!', 'Incorrect credentials')
```

Comment: in your example "login_info" is unused however i do agree on nto keeping the file open. can you edit this?